# Calculate on rsync output with wc -l

Tags: rsync, bash-scripting

When I run an bash script, I want to know how many files were moved with `rsync`.

I though about doing a calculation like this
`$(rsync -avz ./* ./ | wc -l)-4`

The minus 4 is because rsync always outputs its default stats about the transfer.

bash clearly doesn't work like this.

Any other approach is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Math expressions can be done using the `$(( ))` expansion (or the old `$[ ]` equivalent).

```
lines=$(rsync -avz ./* ./ | wc -l)
files=$(( lines - 4 ))
```

(You can actually use `$( )` directly inside `$(( ))`, but that'll be more difficult to read later.)

It can also be done using an assignment inside `(( ))`:

```
lines=$(rsync -avz ./* ./ | wc -l)
(( files = lines - 4 ))
```

If the `files` variable is declared as an integer, this will be automatic:

```
declare -i files=lines-4
```